# Is there a way to access the input object after it was piped?

Tags: powershell, pipeline, anonymous-function

Is there a way to pipe a whole object through a pipeline and process mentioned Object in one step? Put simply the $PSItem Variable on the other side of my pipeline should have the same value as the whole object which was put through the pipe.

I've found the following method to have a sort of anonymous functions in posh though this processes every item in the input object separately (As this is what the process block in advanced functions is meant for).

Therefor the code:

`Get-Service | & {process {return $_.length}}`

Returns:
1 1 1 1 1 1 1..

What I'm looking for is a way to access the full object with the $_/$PSItem variable after the pipeline and process it further / return properties of this object.

Comment: use the comma operator - something like this >>> `,@(Get-Service) |` <<< otta work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  You can use -pipelinevariable with get-service if you need to access it 2 pipes down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Process Block in PowerShell can take single member arrays as its input which then leads it to use the whole member of the array to process rather then all members of the Object.

Using the comma operator one can create a single member array in a simple fashion.
[Further information about Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6)

The following code uses the comma operator to put the object array which is returned by `Get-Process` into a single member array.

```
,(Get-Process)
```

You are now free to use the object in the pipeline and access properties of it.

```
,(Get-Process) | & {process {if($_.length -ge 10) {return "Greater / equals 10"}else{return "Smaller than 10"}}}
```